# How to handle Get.arguments as null in GetxController

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I have following GetX controller to pass parameters to page in Flutter:

**UPDATED**

```
class HomeController extends GetxController {

  File image;
  String ocr_text;

  onInit(){
    super.onInit();

    image = Get.arguments['image'];
    ocr_text = Get.arguments['ocr_text'];

    update();
  }

}
```

Binding:

```
class HomeBinding extends Bindings {
  @override
  void dependencies() {
    Get.lazyPut<HomeController>(() => HomeController());
  }
}
```

I want to pass **image** from Ocr_details page:

```
FlatButton(
            color: Colors.blue,
            child: Icon(Icons.save_outlined),
              onPressed: () {
                Get.toNamed(
                  AppRoutes.HOME,
                  arguments: {'image': controller.image, 'ocr_text': controller.text},
                );
              }
          ),
```

to home page:

**UPDATED:**

```
Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(32),
                child:  GetBuilder<HomeController>(
                  builder: (_) {
                    return _.image != null
                        ? Image.file(_.image)
                        : Container();
                  },
                ),
              ),
```

**GetPages**

```
class AppPages {
  static var list = [
    GetPage(
      name: AppRoutes.HOME,
      page: () => HomePage(),
      binding: HomeBinding(),
    ),
    GetPage(
      name: AppRoutes.PICK_IMAGE,
      page: () => PickImagePage(),
      binding: PickImageBinding(),
    ),
    GetPage(
      name: AppRoutes.OCR_DETAILS,
      page: () => OCRDetailsPage(),
      binding: OCRDetailsBinding(),
    )
  ];
}
```

**Routes**

```
class AppRoutes {
  static const String HOME = '/';
  static const String PICK_IMAGE = '/pick_image';
  static const String OCR_DETAILS = '/ocr_details';
}
```

But I'm getting following error:
*The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building HomePage(dirty):
The method '[]' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling:*

I dont know if there is a way to check if argument is null and continue with rendering a widget?

Comment: When you navigate to HOME, are you on an overlay widget like a Dialog or someting? because I had this error before when I tried to pass arguments to Get.arguments from overlay widgets. It should work fine if it's from a regular page.

Answer (score 1):

First, You are not using **@override** annotation with the **onInit()**. Second, You need to change the GetxController's **onReady()**. On ready will be called after the UI loads.

Instead of

```
class HomeController extends GetxController {

  File image;
  String ocr_text;

  onInit(){
    super.onInit();

    image = Get.arguments['image'];
    ocr_text = Get.arguments['ocr_text'];

    update();
  }
}
```

Try:

```
class HomeController extends GetxController {

  File image;
  String ocr_text;

  @override
  onReady(){
    super.onReady();

    image = Get.arguments['image'];
    ocr_text = Get.arguments['ocr_text'];

    update();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On the page where do you want to receive,

```
final args = Get.arguments;


class HomeController extends GetxController {

  final args = Get.arguments;
 
}
Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(32),
                child:  GetBuilder<HomeController>(
                  builder: (_) {
                    return args.image != null
                        ? Image.file(args.image)
                        : Container();
                  },
                ),
              ),],
```

then  when you need it
`args.image` or `args.ocr_text`

Comment: Thank you very much for help, but now I got this error:
The getter 'image' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: image

Comment: probably not passing right, print(args), then see if it is object or list or null,  then args['image'] or args.image

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
class HomeController extends GetxController {

   final File image = Get.arguments['image'];
   final String ocr_text = Get.arguments['ocr_text'];

}
```

Use this:

```
class HomeController extends GetxController {

    File image;
    String ocr_text;

    onInit(){
      super.onInit();

      image = Get.arguments['image'];
      ocr_text = Get.arguments['ocr_text'];
      
      update();
   }

}
```

**Update**

I can see you are using `controller.image`. Instead of `controller.image` you need to use `_.image` inside your **GetBuilder**

**Update 2**
Just check if `Get.arguments` isn't **null** before trying to get the arguments and assigning.

```
class HomeController extends GetxController {

    File image;
    String ocr_text;

    onInit(){
      super.onInit();

      if(Get.arguments != null){
        image = Get.arguments['image'];
        ocr_text = Get.arguments['ocr_text'];
      }
      
   }

}
```

Comment: I got this error:
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building Container(padding: EdgeInsets.all(32.0)):
The method '[]' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: []("image")

Comment: I can see you are calling controller.image, you should call _.image

Comment: I updated code as it is in first post, but still got his error:

The method '[]' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: []("image")

Comment: Can you please include your Routes definition/GetPages?

Comment: Routes definition and GetPages added

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem. I have created a new project and tried reproducing it. But in my case, it's working without any issues.  Although I am using null-safe Flutter and not passing the 'image' file, I was able to send 'ocr_text' from 'OCRDetailsPage' to 'HomePage'. You can take a look at the reop: https://github.com/smjxpro/flutter_stackoverflow/tree/getx_handle_get_arguments_in_controller

Comment: Thank you very much for help. I think in your case it works ok, because initilal page is OCR Details page, so ocr_text is not null when passing to home page.
In my case initial page is Home page (without oct_text), than you are going to ocr details page and return value from there. You can see my code in here:
https://github.com/ertiusmeo/OCR_GetX

Comment: Now I can see what's your problem! Please check the updated answer! Hope it will fix the issue.

Comment: But onInit() will be called only when we initialize the widget (Home page), so now ocr_text and image won't be passed from OCR_Details page, because onInit wont be called again.

Answer (score 0):

This is a late answer, but If someone faces this issue in 2023 still when you are using `GetPageRoute` please pass the `generateRoute(RouteSettings settings)` param to the
`settings` param in `GetPageRoute`.
Ex:

```
return GetPageRoute<bool?>(
          settings: settings,
          page: () => YourScreen(),
          binding: YourBinding(),
          transition: Transition.downToUp,
        );
```

Comment: This is still giving me null when getting the arguments I am passing. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
 final args = Get.arguments ?? "";
```

check is there any arguments or not
then check for

```
 final data = Get.arguments["data"] ?? "";
```